# Pset7 numb3r; failed check50

Tags: python, cs50

I am doing [problem set 7](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/7/numb3rs/); my code output True or False as per instruction but it didn't pass check50.

check50 returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/tmp2vk2c_gh/test_correct_ipv4_localhost/testing.py", line 3, in \<module\>
print(validate(input("IPv4 Address: ")))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/tmp2vk2c_gh/test_correct_ipv4\_...
```

Kindly assist.

Here is my code

```
import re

def main():
    # prompting use for IPV4
     ip = input("IPv4 Address: ")
     numbers = get_num(ip)
     print(validate(numbers))

def get_num(ip):
    # search for a valid IPV4 sequence in a string
    m = re.search(r"^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$", ip)
    if m:
        # convert each group in a sequence to an int
        number1 = int(m.group(1))
        number2 = int(m.group(2))
        number3 = int(m.group(3))
        number4 = int(m.group(4))
        # return a list of numbers
        return [number1, number2, number3, number4]
    # if no match found return None
    else:
        return None

# validate ip address
def validate(numbers):
    # if there was a match
    if numbers:
        for number in numbers:
            # check if each number in
            if 0 <= number <= 255:
                number = number
            else:
                return False
        return True

    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please describe the task.

Comment: So it seems they only want one function (validate). When I changed to one function it passed check50.

Comment: Can someone explain to me what the previous check50 output means? I have the output in the question above. Thank you so much.

Comment: `check50` tests `numb3rs.py` and `test_numb3rs.py`. You didn't post `test_numb3rs.py` Maybe the problem is in your test code?

Comment: Thank you @kcw78; test code passed all tests. No that my  new code passed check50;  I just want to know what the "traceback(most recent call last)...." error means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I look at the traceback more closely and compare to the code above, I see why the error occurs. I will explain.
The last line of the traceback displays the line with the error. It is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
print(validate(input("IPv4 Address: ")))
```

This is what the Python interpreter was trying to execute when the error occurs. It also tells you this is line 3 in file `testing.py`. So, the error isn't in your code (per se), but when `testing.py` calls your code.

Now, look at your `main()` function (code snippet below):

```
 ip = input("IPv4 Address: ")
 numbers = get_num(ip)
 print(validate(numbers))
```

Notice how `input()` returns `ip`. You then call `get_num(ip)` which returns `numbers`, and THEN it calls `print(validate(numbers))`. You have an extra step between `input()` and `validate()` that is not in the testing code. That's not how your program is supposed to work. You should get the input and call `validate()` directly -- no intermediate functions. That's why it doesn't work when called from `testing.py`.

I assume you fixed the error by migrating `get_num()` into the `validate()` function?

Comment: That is what I did. I had to move get_num() to validate().